# Sitecore commerce 10 visual studio setup issue

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I tried to setup the development environment for Sitecore Commerce 10 with visual studio. I can able to run `Customer.sample.solution` without any build error but while trying to navigate to the Business tool it shows below error message in the log file.

```
ERROR SQL.GetEntities.Fail: Id='List-CONTENTPATHS-ByDate'|Environment='Entity-CommerceEnvironment-HabitatAuthoring'|Message='Login failed for user 'xxx/yyy'.'|Number='18456'|Procedure=''|Line='65536'|Number='18456'
ERROR CtxMsg.Error.SqlException: Text=SQL:block:findentitiesinlist.Exception: Login failed for user 'xxx/yyy'.
ERROR Pipeline completed with errorSystem.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.Definitions.AddPipelineBlockDefinition`1.Build(IServiceProvider services)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.DefaultPipelineBlockRunner.RunAsync[TOutput](String name, Object input, IPipelineExecutionContext context)
ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager.Error: Message=The operation was canceled.|Trace=   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequestAsync(CommerceContext commerceContext, String action, String method, ItemModel itemModel)
```

and in browser console
[image]

Steps that I followed:

1. I did changes in `sitecorebizfx config.json` for both (*EngineUri and bizfxuri*).
2. I updated *AllowedOrigins* of `wwwroot/config.json` and `launchsettings.json`("COMMERCEENGINE_AppSettings__AllowedOrigins").
3. I have updated the SQL database username, password, servername in `Global.json`, `launchsettings.json`, `Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` file.
4. I have added the localhost URL in `Sitecore.Commerce.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file.
5. I have changed the *shopServiceUrl* and *commerceOpsServiceurl* in `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config` file.
6. Finally stopped the CommerceAuthoring site, restarted the IIS and clear the browser cache.

so can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Double check the engine https url, Is 5000 the right default port for https? or should it be 5001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you bootstrap commerce engine after changing SQL connection setting in Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json file? if not, then please do it and also do iisreset or apppool recycle of commerce engine after that.

Comment: Thankyou for your response ,it is very helpful